# using Aura:If , inside the Aura:Iteration

Tags: aura-iteration

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.contacts}" var="item" indexVar="idx">
  <aura:if isTrue="{!lessthan(idx,5)}"> 
        <ui:outputText value="{!ind}" />
  </aura:if>
</aura:iteration>
```

Although, "contacts" list got more than 7 elements ... it never enters the Aura: If condition?

thanks
If i remove " aura:if " condition 7 rows get populated.

Comment: could you please add your code - without code, we will not be able to assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bugs in your code is using   <s>`<aura:if isTrue="{!lessthan(idx,5)}">`</s> for lessthan use `&lt;` i.e):`<aura:if isTrue="{!idx &lt; 2}">`

Example  Code:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
<aura:iteration items="[1,2,3,4,5]" var="item" indexVar="idx">
  <aura:if isTrue="{!idx &lt; 2}"> 
        <ui:outputText value="{!item}" />
  </aura:if>
</aura:iteration></aura:application>
```

Comment: thanks, Vignesh ... but in sf documentation  there is no mention of it ..https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm

Comment: @Sumanth it is mentioned . see Comparison Functions in that link